# Python dictionary groupby key then count other key values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Assuming I have 4 dictionaries

`x = {'id': 1, 'addressed_to': 2, 'status': 'open'}`

`y = {'id': 2, 'addressed_to': 2, 'status': 'open'}`

`z = {'id': 3, 'addressed_to': 2, 'status': 'closed'}`

`z = {'id': 4, 'addressed_to': 3, 'status': 'open'}`

I am interested in getting something like this

`result = [{'addressed_to': 2, 'open': 2, 'closed':1},{'addressed_to':3 , 'open': 1, 'closed':0} ]`

How can I archive this in python3?

Comment: I don't actually get you... If you grouped it by `"addressed_to"` , it should be 3 not 2. your last variable name is the same as third one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible answer is to move the dictionaries to a list and iterate thru them to get the required answers. Sample code below. The keys for the result dictionary are values of addressed_to

```
data_list = {"statsdata": [
                   {'id': 1, 'addressed_to': 2, 'status': 'open'},
                   {'id': 2, 'addressed_to': 2, 'status': 'open'},
                   {'id': 3, 'addressed_to': 2, 'status': 'closed'},
                   {'id': 4, 'addressed_to': 3, 'status': 'open'}
                 ] }

    
p_result = {}
def checkItem(item):
    if item["status"] == "open":
            p_result[item["addressed_to"]]["open"] += 1
    if item["status"] == "closed":
            p_result[item["addressed_to"]]["closed"] += 1
    

for item in data_list["statsdata"]:
    if item["addressed_to"] not in p_result:
        p_result[item["addressed_to"]] = {'open':0, 'closed': 0}
        checkItem(item)
    else:
        checkItem(item)


print(p_result)
```

Result will appear as

```
 {2: {'open': 2, 'closed': 1}, 3: {'open': 1, 'closed': 0}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This will do it